# Get latest file merge name azure devops

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I am working on proof of concept for my project. One of the requirement is to get name of the file latest committed to the main branch. I am calling below command from Azure pipeline.

```
$a = git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $(Build.SourceVersion)
```

It works fine when I am directly committing file to the main branch.
When I create another branch and add file to it and then merge it with main branch and when i try the same command it does not fetch me any value. Alternatively I also tried `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD`, but this command don't return any value when is file is added to main branch during merge process. Any pointer or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the latest commit hash, from the `main` branch, regardless of whether that's a merge or not using this command:

```sh
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H" main
```

You should then be able to plumb this in to your existing command like:

```sh
 git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $(git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H" main)
```

P.S. you can restrict it to merges, or non-merges by adding the `--merge` or `--no-merges` switches, respectively.

Comment: Simpler than `git log -n -1`: `git rev-parse main`. (For script robustness, replace `main` with `refs/heads/main` regardless of which of these you use.) But note that you don't have to do this at all: `git diff-tree` accepts, as its various tree-ish arguments, branch names! So `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r main HEAD` will compare the snapshot in `main` to the one in `HEAD`, for instance.